# linux: how to remove file with this kind of name "test\download\"?

Tags: linux, file, ssh

I was trying to remove this file from server using rm command but it doesn't work. Also I can't rename this file. Please help.

Comment: What is the error message and return code ?

Comment: And what are you typing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
rm -i test?download*
```

and read [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) and [rm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html)